# triggering same function for multiple select box in different containers

Tags: jquery

I have select box inside multiple divs which shows the selected option value in span div. the jquery function executes only for the first div select box and not for the rest. i want a single function that works for all the divs without repeating code for each and every div.

```
<div class="format-block">
  <span class="format-title">Format:</span>
  <select id="format3" class="selectpicker" name="for" >
    <option value="48.00" selected="selected">Paperback</option>
    <option value="40.00">eBook</option>
  </select>                                    
  <span id="price-div3" >
    <span class="price"></span>
  </span> 
</div>

<div class="format-block">
  <span class="format-title">Format:</span>
  <select id="format4" class="selectpicker" name="for" >
    <option value="48.00" selected="selected">Paperback</option>
    <option value="40.00">eBook</option>
  </select>
  <span id="price-div4">
    <span class="price"></span>
  </span> 
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {      
  var format_div = $(".format-block select").attr("id");
  $(".format-block span.price").html("£" + $("#" + format_div).val());

  $('.format-block').on("change", "select", function() { 
    $(".format-block span.price").html("£" + $("#" + format_div).val());
  });
});
```

pls let me know what im doing wrong here..

Comment: Please take care to format your question so it's readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/), the DOM element that initiated the event. You need to perform operation in its context.

```js
$('.format-block').on("change", "select", function(event) {
  $(event.target).closest(".format-block").find("span.price").html("£" + $(event.target).val());
});

//Tigger event handler, to set the price
$('.format-block select').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="format-block">
  <span class="format-title">Format:</span>
  <select id="format3" class="selectpicker" name="for">
    <option value="48.00" selected>Paperback</option>
    <option value="40.00">eBook</option>
  </select>
  <span id="price-div3">
    <span class="price"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="format-block">
  <span class="format-title">Format:</span>
  <select id="format4" class="selectpicker" name="for">
    <option value="48.00">Paperback</option>
    <option value="40.00" selected>eBook</option>
  </select>
  <span id="price-div4">
    <span class="price"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

References

1. [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
2. [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
3. [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: also the selectbox should show the default selected option before change..Thks